# Shell Script - How do I add and save a new XML element to an XML file?

Tags: xml, shell, netbeans

I'm doing a task relevant to manipulating Netbeans project config files, which requires me to add a new XML element to an XML file.
For example, say I have this XML file in `/home/myusername/Desktop/testxml.xml`, whose content is:

```
<project name="example" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Description 1: The first description</description>
</project>
```

What I want to do now is I want to write a **shell script** that when it executes, it will add **(and save)** a new XML element like so:

```
<description>Description 2: The second description</description>
```

... to the `testxml.xml` file, so that this file will become like this:

```
<project name="example" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Description 1: The first description</description>
    <description>Description 2: The second description</description>
</project>
```

How would I do that ?

Comment: try http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php or sed